# using Java EE BeanManager as Singleton

Tags: jakarta-ee, caching, singleton, glassfish-3, bean-manager

In my Java EE aplication I use the following snippet to obtain BeanManager

```
public static BeanManager getBeanManager() {
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        return (BeanManager) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to retrieve BeanManager!", e);
    }
}
```

**Would it be safe** to use BeanManager as singleton, so I would not have to lookup in initial context each time I need BeenManager?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the BeanManager into a standard EE(v6-v7) component then it is perfectly legal and recommended to simply do:

```
@Inject BeanManager beanManager
```

Comment: Unfortunally I use BeanManager within Java EE components, which do not provide a way of using CDI. One of them is ExceptionMapper. Actually it is the reason why I need a BeanManager in the first place, I need to have a way to access EJBs

Comment: I am using wildfly 8.1.0.Final which comes with weld 2.1 and resteasy 3.0.8 and can use @Inject inside ExceptionMapper.

Comment: If you're really stuck I suggest to use delta spike Bean Manager Provider: https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/core.html#BeanManagerProvider

Comment: well I am kinda stuck with Glassfish 3. For me injection to ExceptionMapper does not work there. I am not sure whether I am able to convince my team to use DeltaSpike. But thank you for the hint!